# TableAdapter does Pentium Math

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a project where a user can enter a decimal in a textbox.  Now I take that value and tryparse it into a nullable float variable, which I pass to a tableAdapter to Insert or Update the DB.

Now here is where it gets wierd, if I give it a value of .24, that is what gets passed to the tableAdapter, however, when I look at what is saved to the database, it is transformed into 0.239999994635582.

I debuged it up to the insert call of the TableAdapter, and it is being passed a value of .24.  My SQL server database column has a type of float.

Any idea on why this could be happening?  Do I need to switch to decimal?

Thanks

Comment: decimal? or double/float? because that 0.239999994635582 is typical of  double/float and it is expected behavior.

Comment: float, as he said. Have a look at my answer

Comment: @Luxspes: everything is defined as a float, no doubles.

Comment: double and float will behave the same.

Comment: Why are you using `FLOAT`? Try using `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` instead. `FLOAT` behaves this way for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the internal power of 2 representation of
float numbers.

Some fractional values cannot be represented very well.

Read more here: [IEEE 754 Floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Switching to decimal will work here, but also has impact to the performance.
(somewhat 10 times slower than float, but you probably will never notice it)

Comment: I can't believe that this is something that float just can't handle (at least on the DB side, C# side seems to handle it just fine). I started feeding lots of very simple numbers into it, and more came out wrong than right. Floating points are just that worthless in SQL server?

Comment: Floating points are "that worthless" *in binary*.  Read the link!

Comment: @Limey - You might as well say the same thing about decimal!  How do you represent the value 1/3 excatly in decimal?  Or PI?  Or Sqrt(2)?  It's the same here.  Some floating point numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: Agreed, that for on running numbers, you will eventually have to truncate or round, however, I was giving it a shorter number that a float should easiy be able to hold; and it have me a longer one. If I can't assign a float with such a simple value as .24 or .17, I don't see much value in it.

Comment: You can use a float here, but you will have to round to get a good result. Decimal should be used with currency values, but this was not a requirement here.